# Error with nested Ternary Operators Requires Explicit Parentheses in PHP 8.0

Tags: php, if-statement, deprecated, conditional-operator

I have recently upgraded to php 8.0 and a theme (admittedly old) I am using has a nested ternary which causes problems as it is deprecated.  I have tried to unravel it but am stumped. Could someone help me figure out the proper parenthesis placements.

This is the code I am trying to 'upgrade'

```
$there_is_skills = 'yes';
 (
! empty( $aboutus_feature1_title ) || ! empty( $aboutus_feature1_text ) ? $there_is_skills = 'yes' :
! empty( $aboutus_feature2_title ) || ! empty( $aboutus_feature2_text ) ? $there_is_skills = 'yes' :
! empty( $aboutus_feature3_title ) || ! empty( $aboutus_feature3_text ) ? $there_is_skills = 'yes' :
! empty( $aboutus_feature4_title ) || ! empty( $aboutus_feature4_text ) ? $there_is_skills = 'yes' :
$there_is_skills = '' );
```

Actually any code that will work - grin

Thanks!

Comment: By default ternaries are grouped from left to right. So add parentheses that match that grouping.

Comment: This is horrible code, BTW. Assignments shouldn't be put inside the ternary. The ternary should be used to return a value that's assigned to the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be turned into a single `if` statement.

```
if (!empty($aboutus_feature1_title) || !empty($aboutus_feature1_text) ||
    !empty($aboutus_feature2_title) || !empty($aboutus_feature2_text) ||
    !empty($aboutus_feature3_title) || !empty($aboutus_feature3_text) ||
    !empty($aboutus_feature4_title) || !empty($aboutus_feature4_text)) {
    $there_is_skills = 'yes';
} else {
    $there_is_skills = '';
}
```

Comment: I'd just concatenate all the strings. If the result is not empty, then there are skills (to pay bills and whatnot)

Comment: @Phil Good idea, although `!empty()` has the feature of not complaining if the variable isn't set.

Comment: Good catch, didn't consider that

Comment: Thank you @Barmar! - that did the trick. I had tried to do a simple if - but got too many if-elses in there.

Comment: It helps to look at it as a whole and figure out the logic.